# How do I prevent an https response from throwing an AuthenticationException with Fiddler running?

Tags: c#, https, httpwebrequest, fiddler

Relative newbie to C# here :)

I'm currently creating a web link scraper and having issues with the responses I'm getting when trying to login to the website via my program. I'm trying to use Fiddler to see if my program is sending the proper data, but my program is throwing an AuthenticationException when trying to get a response from the site with Fiddler running. The requests are being sent over HTTPS and Fiddler's certificate is the cause of the excepting being thrown.

My question is, what can I implement into my program to have it disregard the certificate authentication? As far as my program goes, the requests and responses are being handled by HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse classes.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Sorry bout that. I'll keep that in mind for the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you done the following:
[Fiddler https decryption](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/help/httpsdecryption.asp)

Comment: Set that up just now and it does work. Didn't know which was going to be more of a hassle, installing and uninstalling the certificate or implementing the fix inside my code. I guess I'll take the former route for now :)